# Less Jupiter than Icarus

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrases

What does "Less Jupiter than Icarus" mean in the following sentence?

> Less Jupiter than Icarus, Emmanuel Macron came crashing down this week.

The sentence is taken from the latest [*The Economist*](https://www.economist.com/leaders/2022/06/22/what-president-emmanuel-macron-should-learn-from-losing-his-majority-in-the-french-parliament). Does it have something to do with their Greek meanings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Less *X* than *Y***, where X and Y are nouns, is a structure that we use to mean "not very much like X, and more like Y" or "not really an X, but a Y".

So the sentence is saying, basically, "*Looking less like Jupiter and more like Icarus*, Emmanuel Macron came crashing down this week."

Yes, this refers to the characters from Greek mythology.  Jupiter was the king of the gods; Icarus was a man who tried to fly too close to the sun and fell to earth.  So the meaning of the sentence is "*Looking less like the king of the gods, and more like the famous man who flew too high and fell to earth,* Emmanuel Macron came crashing down this week."

Other examples:

- ["...less a social occasion than a medical appointment..."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/More_Than_a_Dream/ahStCgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22less%20a%22%20%22than%20a%22&pg=PT81&printsec=frontcover)
- ["The home, however, is less a container than a membrane..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=93S7aCK0AP8C&pg=PA85&dq=%22less%20a%22%20%22than%20a%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbksXcgM_4AhVkElkFHVSHA6U4ChDoAXoECAIQAg)
- ["He was less a painter than a religious illustrator..."](https://books.google.com/books?id=V5JOAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA24-PA26&dq=%22he%20was%20less%20a%22%20%22than%20a%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBo_2Ngc_4AhW8ElkFHSd3BHgQ6AF6BAgEEAI)

Comment: I think that it's even a bit more critical, because Icarus wasn't really a famous man (at that time) but merely the rash son (perhaps a young boy or teenager) of Daedalus.